# Fancyhdr: Starred Sections

Tags: fancyhdr

Using `fancyhdr` package, this is what I do for each of my starred sections to print them at the header, e.g.:

```
\chapter*{{Foreword}} \markboth{{Foreword}}{Foreword}
```

and this what I have in the relative sections of my preamble:

```
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\normalfont\scriptsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\small {My Book}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\small\\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
```

How can I automate it so that I do not have to do it manually for each starred section?

With my (very) limited knowledge, I tried,

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
```

From the `fancyhr` package manual, but it didn't work.

MWE: (Exported from LyX):

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{ITC Goudy Sans Std Book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc,paperheight=48pc]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=9pc,bmargin=6pc,lmargin=5pc,rmargin=5pc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{yfonts,color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{section}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\normalsize\filcenter}
{\normalsize\MakeUppercase{\thechapter} }
{0pt}
{\vspace{1pt}%
\normalsize}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{80pt}


\titleformat{\section}
{\itshape\normalsize\filright}
{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.}}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{60pt}{60pt}

\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\normalfont\scriptsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\small {My Book}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\small\\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage%
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You could use a KOMA-class, that take care of this by using `\addchap`, or use package [unnumberedtotoc](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc).

Comment: Can you turn your code fragments into a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2693) for people to play with?

Comment: since you have titlesec why do you use fancyhdr?

Comment: @touhami The two packages aim to quite different purposes.

Comment: @egreg I think what touhami is referring to is the `pagestyles` option of `titlesec` which uses the `titleps` package, which implements headers and footers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `\markboth` to the `numberless` version of `\chapter`. I reorganized the call to packages and the settings. Remove `kantlipsum` at the end that's only used for generating mock text in the example.

Note that `emptypage` avoids the redefinition of `\cleardoublepage` by hand.

This doesn't spare you from issuing `\addcontentsline` if you need the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[english]{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc,paperheight=48pc]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=9pc,bmargin=6pc,lmargin=5pc,rmargin=5pc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{emptypage} % avoids redefining \cleardoublepage

\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\normalsize\filcenter}
  {\normalsize\thechapter\ }
  {0pt}
  {\vspace{1pt}\normalsize}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\normalsize\filcenter}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\vspace{1pt}\normalsize\addchaptertitle}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{80pt}

\newcommand{\addchaptertitle}[1]{%
  #1\markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\itshape\normalsize\filright}
  {\thesection.}
  {.5em}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{60pt}{60pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\normalfont\scriptsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\small My Book}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\small\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}

\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{ITC Goudy Sans Std Book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % mock text

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter*{Introduction}

\kant[1-4]

\chapter{First}

\kant[5-8]

\end{document}
```

I'll show only page 3 which has the required header.

[image]

Comment: Would you kindly tell me how I can tweak the relevant section in your code for numberless sections. That is, say, each header displays the book title and the section (including the numberless ones).

Comment: @blackened Replace the two `\fancyhead` lines with `\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily\small My Book --- \leftmark}`

Comment: Respectfully, that gives Book Title and Chapter Name; I would like to have Book Title and Section Name, and rightmark gives empty for numberless sections.

Comment: @blackened That's a different question, then